# Jhipster session timeout

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster

In my application there is use of `Jhipster` , `Spring Boot` , `Spring Security` , `Rest API` , `Angular js` , `Spring boot`.
 I know that we can set session timeout value in `yml` file.
But what i wanted to understand is how is the time interval calculated in such applications.

Ex: Suppose session `timeout= 60` secs.

User logs in and keep the browser idle for 70 seconds. Now after 70 seconds when the user hits some button. A pop is displayed. So I wanted to know where is the calculation for difference in the two rest end points calls is done because after session timeout interval if i hit any api i get session timeout.

Answer (score 2):

The session timeout is computed by the embedded servlet engine (Jetty, Tomcat or Undertow), it keeps a collection of all active sessions and the time of last access.

On first request, a session object is created in server and a session cookie containing its id is sent back in response, server also stores in session object the time of last access.

When your second request is processed, the server extracts the session id from the session cookie then finds session object matching this id and compares current time with last access time.

Comment: I am trying this solution: I created an unsecured Endpoint and i am planning to hit this end point every 30sec. I will pass the username as the parameter.